# What are the criteria for the stopwatch stamp?

Tags: battleblock-theater

On the level complete screen there is a bronze stopwatch or clock stamp/badge alongside the green gems and the yarn ball), but there is no time information as to what triggers it. Is the stamp based off of completion time or some other factor, like deaths? If based on completion time, which co-op player's exit stops the timer? How does it differ between levels and difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

The only criteria is the **Level Time**, although it is not displayed in the story mode.

> Level Time is a certain amount of time assigned to the level.
>   Players must complete the level before running out of time to earn the badge.

Comment: Please add the source of the quote

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the checkpoints in some level's there is a time listed on each one of them.  This is the time (or sooner) that you should hit these checkpoints.  If you hit each checkpoint before the time shown(and make it to the end in a reasonable time) You should get the Stopwatch Stamp.

I am trying to figure out if it is only the time trial levels that this shows up on or if it is all of them.  I will try to edit this answer when I find out.

Comment: As far as I know that is not correct, the times in the checkpoints are the times of your previous runs, the first time you run a level they have no time at all.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly we finish game based on the time taken i.e. clearing obstacles and encountering difficulties of level and reaching the exit. Early they finishes and earn higher rank.

In other case you may calculate based on tries made and time taken.